# Constructing A Type of Function

Tags: functions, integers

Let $f(a,b)$ be a continuous function that is only an integer when $a$ and $b$ are both integers. What is one such definition of $f(a,b)$?

Comment: Something like $\frac 13\times \left( \sin^2 (\pi a)+\sin^2 (\pi b)\right)$ for instance.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. I already know about those along the form of $b \times \left( \sin^2 (\pi a)+\sin^2 (\pi b)\right)$. I was hoping for some that don't include trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, $$f(a,b)=\min\left\{\left(a-\left\lfloor a\right\rfloor\right)^2+\left(b-\left\lfloor b\right\rfloor\right)^2;\left(a-\left\lceil a\right\rceil\right)^2+\left(b-\left\lfloor b\right\rfloor\right)^2; \left(a-\left\lceil a\right\rceil\right)^2+\left(b-\left\lceil b\right\rceil\right)^2;\left(a-\left\lfloor a\right\rfloor\right)^2+\left(b-\left\lceil b\right\rceil\right)^2\right\}$$

It is continuous, and it satisfies $0\le f(a,b)\le \frac{1}2$ and $f(a,b)=0\iff (a,b)\in\Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: Ok, I will test it and come back to you.

Comment: Ok, It's good, but I'll wait for some others before I accept.

Comment: @Gae. S. I finally studied your answer and gave it an upvote but I have a question. Does the $min$ mean taking the lowest of the four options separated by semicolons? If so, I gather it is to avoid picking one where the sum of squares turns $f(a,b),a,b\notin\mathbb{N}$ into an integer. I also didn't understand how $f(a,b)\le\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @poetasis Yes, it means the least of those quantities. The essential idea is that given any metric space $(X,d)$ a non-empty subset $A\subseteq X$, the function $d(\bullet,A)$ defined by $d(x,A)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in A\}$ is continuous and, moreover, $d(x,A)=0\iff x\in\overline A$. It turns out that $f(a,b)=(d((a,b),\Bbb Z^2))^2$ in the usual euclidean metric of $\Bbb R^2$, because you need only care about the four points $(\lfloor a\rfloor,\lfloor b\rfloor)$ et cetera. It is $\le\frac12$ because $2^{-1/2}$ is the furthest from the corners of a $1\times1$ square you can get while staying inside.